how to remove postgresql completely?
in my kubuntu postgres is install but i have to remove from my system.
but when remove from my system by this command
dpkg -l | grep postgres

and :
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-common

I get this message
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg

E: The list of sources could not be read.
command was used to install :
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

what to do???

What command was used to install the app?

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

Do not put that in comments please edit the question and add the info.
